# How to recognize the start and end of a zpool partition on byte/HDD block level or with broken GPT?

Tags: linux, partitioning, zfs

In case the GPT of a HDD has been deleted and possibly some partitons, but not the one that should be found with the answer to this question (because it is right in the middle of the HDD and writing to that section is very unlikely regarding the mechanism used to overwrite the GPT) how would one get started to find the end and start of a zpool partition?

Background[1]: I invoked `zpool create /dev/sda` instead of `zpool create /dev/sdaX`. The command failed after some seconds with an error message which I don't remember and can't reconstruct. I'm trying now to get started with the search and eventually improve the `gpart` program with a module[2] (the search in `gpart` didn't turn up any results so far).

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04-amd64 with Linux 3.13 and `zfsonlinux` 0.6.3.

---

[1] Background information is background information: Please try to answer the question in its abstract form rather than providing a solution concerning the background information only.

[2] https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gpart/+bug/1382666

Answer (score 0):

The `zdb` command can be used to find block addresses, in a few different ways.

You might try the `-b` option for a block listing, `-d` for pool-centric info including block addresses, or `-m` for metaslab detail. And zdb options work in this cool/weird way, where you repeat the option more than once for increased verbosity -- so you might try something like,

```
zdb -bbbb [pool | dataset]
```

for a super-verbose readout of block detail. Zdb can get ridiculously detailed about the on-disk format of data, so I'd expect w/ enough digging and reading you can find any info you need, for anything.

Check this man page, the one shipped w/ most OSs is garbage: https://www.illumos.org/man/1m/zdb

And here's a nice write up (of an old version, still basically the same) by Ben Rockwood: http://www.cuddletech.com/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=980

Comment: @karl Did ZDB help you at all?

Answer (score 0):

`testdisk` 7.0 recognizes the paritioning correctly after a "deep search" which can be run after the quick search which might not return results.